# Add time in PHP

Tags: php, time

How can I add a given number of time in PHP?

Below is are three time variables I would like to add:

```
time1: "00:02:00"
time2: "00:15:00"
time3: "00:08:00"
```

This was my approach in attempting to achieve that:

```
echo date('h:i:s', strtotime('00:02:00') + strtotime('00:15:00') + strtotime('00:08:00'));
```

The result of my code is **`12:25:00`**, while the expected result should have been **`00:25:00`**.

What am I doing wrong and how can I add given time variables effectively in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from `h` into `H`.

`h` => 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

`H` => 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

Try

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('00:02:00') + strtotime('00:15:00') + strtotime('00:08:00'));
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Don't understand, this is the same code I use.. and it get the wrong result

Comment: Perhaps you should have looked at the result that you get before posting this answer, and remembered that strtotime adds a date into that equation to give a unix timestamp

Comment: @user2673664 Please mark tick on my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've had several issues handling time in php.

The best way I've ever found it was this (and that way even if your calculation goes through 24 hours will not generate problems).

```
<?php

function time_to_sec($time) {
list($h, $m, $s) = explode (":", $time);
$seconds = 0;
$seconds += (intval($h) * 3600);
$seconds += (intval($m) * 60);
$seconds += (intval($s));
return $seconds;
}
function sec_to_time($sec) {
return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', floor($sec / 3600), floor($sec / 60 % 60), floor($sec % 60));
}

$time1 = time_to_sec("00:02:00");
$time2 =  time_to_sec("00:15:00");
$time3 = time_to_sec("00:08:00");

$total = $time1 + $time2 + $time3;
var_dump(sec_to_time($total));
?>
```

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this way. it will work.

```
$arr = [
    '00:02:00',
    '00:15:00',
    '00:08:00'
    ];
   $hour =0;$min=0;$sec=0;
   foreach($arr as $a){
      $time = explode(':',$a);
      $sec +=$time[2];
      $min +=$time[1];
      $hour += $time[0];
   }
   echo sprintf('%02d',$hour).':'.sprintf('%02d',$min).':'.sprintf('%02d',$sec);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.This should do what you are looking for:

```
<?php
/**
 * @param array $times
 * @return string
 */
function sumOfDiffrentTime($times = array())
{
    $minutes = '';
    $seconds = '';
    // loop through all the times array
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute;
        $seconds += (intval($second));
    }
    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;

    // returns the  formatted time
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}

$times = array();

$times[] = "00:02:00";
$times[] = "00:15:00";
$times[] = "00:08:00";

// pass your $times array to the function
echo sumOfDiffrentTime($times);
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/703662)